# Primary Key related CQL3 Queries cases & errors when sorting

Tags: cassandra, cql, cql3, cassandra-2.0, datastax

I have two issues while querying Cassandra:

### Query 1

```
> select * from a where author='Amresh' order by tweet_id DESC;
Order by with 2ndary indexes is not supported
```

What I learned: secondary indexes are made to be used only with a `WHERE` clause and not `ORDER BY`? If so, then how can I sort?

### Query 2

```
> select * from a where user_id='xamry' ORDER BY tweet_device DESC;
Order by currently only supports the ordering of columns following their
declared order in the PRIMARY KEY.
```

What I learned: The `ORDER BY` column should be in the 2nd place in the primary key, maybe? If so, then what if I need to sort by multiple columns?

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE a(
  user_id      varchar,
  tweet_id     varchar,
  tweet_device varchar,
  author       varchar,
  body         varchar,
  PRIMARY KEY(user_id,tweet_id,tweet_device)
);

INSERT INTO a (user_id, tweet_id, tweet_device, author, body)
    VALUES ('xamry', 't1', 'web', 'Amresh', 'Here is my first tweet');
INSERT INTO a (user_id, tweet_id, tweet_device, author, body)
    VALUES ('xamry', 't2', 'sms', 'Saurabh', 'Howz life Xamry');
INSERT INTO a (user_id, tweet_id, tweet_device, author, body)
    VALUES ('mevivs', 't1', 'iPad', 'Kuldeep', 'You der?');
INSERT INTO a (user_id, tweet_id, tweet_device, author, body)
    VALUES ('mevivs', 't2', 'mobile', 'Vivek', 'Yep, I suppose');

Create index user_index on a(author);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your questions, let's focus on your choice of primary key for this table:

```
PRIMARY KEY(user_id,tweet_id,tweet_device)
```

As written, the `user_id` will be used as the partition key, which distributes your data around the cluster but also keeps all of the data for the same user ID on the same node.  Within a single partition, unique rows are identified by the pair `(tweet_id, tweet_device)` and those rows will be *automatically ordered* by `tweet_id` because it is the second column listed in the primary key.  (Or put another way, the first column in the PK that is *not* a part of the partition key determines the sort order of the partition.)

### Query 1

The `WHERE` clause is `author='Amresh'`.  Note that this clause does not involve *any* of the columns listed in the primary key; instead, it is filtering using a secondary index on `author`.  Since the WHERE clause does not specify an exact value for the partition key column (`user_id`) using the index involves *scanning **all** cluster nodes* for possible matches.  Results cannot be sorted when they come from more than one replica (node) because that would require holding the entire result set on the coordinator node before it could return any results to the client.  The coordinator can't know what is the *real* "first" result row until it has confirmed that it has received and sorted every possible matching row.

If you need the information for a specific author name, separate from user ID, and sorted by tweet ID, then consider storing the data again in a different table.  The data design philosophy with Cassandra is to *store the data in the format you need when reading it* and to actually denormalize (store redundant information) as necessary.  This is because in Cassandra, *writes are cheap* (though it places the burden of managing multiple copies of the same logical data on the application developer).

### Query 2

Here, the `WHERE` clause is `user_id = 'xamry'` which happens to be the partition key for this table.  The good news is that this will go directly to the replica(s) holding this partition and not bother asking the other nodes.  However, you cannot `ORDER BY tweet_device` because of what I explained at the top of this answer.  Cassandra stores rows (within a single partition) sorted by a single column, generally the second column in the primary key.  In your case, you can access data for `user_id = 'xamry' ORDER BY tweet_id` but not ordered by `tweet_device`.  The answer, if you really need the data sorted by device, is the same as for Query 1: store it in a table where that is the second column in the primary key.

If, when looking up the tweets by `user_id` you only ever need them sorted by device, simply flip the order of the last two columns in your primary key.  If you need to be able to sort either way, store the data twice in two different tables.

The Cassandra storage engine does not offer multi-column sorting other than the order of columns listed in your primary key.

Comment: Thanks a lot, got in-depth understanding :) But what if i have a user table (with many columns eg:80) & I want to order by many column names individually ? Will i need to store the whole table (80 times) again with every time placing the column name at second column position ? Or may be i can make multiple tables with schema <user_id:ColumnToUsewithOrderby1>,<user_id:ColumnToUsewithOrderby1> then get the ordered user_id (array) & then query the main user table (with for each) ?

Comment: If that is what you really need to do, then it doesn't sound like Cassandra is the proper tool.

Comment: Ok, But if i have a table with schema <user_id,age,city,college,weight) & i want to order it by age, weight & city then how should i do, the ways ?

Comment: First you should reevaluate the decisions that led you to start with Cassandra, and do its benefits and features outweigh giving up relational database features like arbitrary, multiple column sorting.

Comment: Actually i'm a student, learning & thinking about all possibilities so that the concept is clear. I haven't gone in production with it. But What companies do when they want to order with other column of the same table (not using two columns at a time, just other column than the 2nd position in the primary key) ?